# Can using simultaneous intrusion detection systems (IDS) create conflicts?

Tags: network, ids, detection, intrusion, system-compromise

Can simultaneously using 2 or more intrusion detection systems (IDS) on the same computer or network create conflicts ?

Talking about tools (as examples) such as but not limited to: tripwire, bro, aide, psad, rkhunter.

Thanks !

Comment: If you are 'detecting', then I can't see what would be conflicting. If you are 'preventing' (IPS) then you could end up with "response race conditions", but it depends how you implement the IPS's (serial or parallel).

Comment: @schroeder indeed it makes sense haha. I'm talking about an intrusion detection not preventing. What are examples of an IPS please ? Is a firewall an IPS ? Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, according to my research you can use multiple IDS on the same computer simultaneously.

> If you are paranoid and have sufficient free time to read all the
>   email, you will be happy to hear that multiple HIDS tools running in
>   parallel do not get in each other's way. In other words, you can run a
>   combination of Tripwire, AIDE, AFICK, Samhain, and OSSEC on a single
>   computer and let the systems monitor one another. But some caution is
>   advised: Updates that arrive at the same time can easily send the
>   system into an infinite loop.
>   http://www.linux-magazine.com/Issues/2016/183/Host-Based-IDS/(offset)/3#article_i4